# How to convert Values from <string> to <double> type in a Deedle frame?

Tags: c#, types, operation, deedle

I need to perform something like:

```
var myTotal = myFrame.Sum();
```

However, the values are *string* type and I get an error.
How could I convert the values of the frame to a *double* type?

I'm using only 3 decimals "0.000", is there anything more practical than *double* that **Deedle** can handle?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

> How could I convert the values of the frame to a double type?

Assuming `myFrame` is some sort of a collection of strings which are parseable to `double`, you'll want to parse those strings first into doubles, and then invoke a sum:

```
var myTotal = myFrame.Sum(x => double.Parse(x));
```

Comment: Short form: `var myTotal = myFrame.Sum(x => double.Parse(x));`

Comment: @General-Doomer Definitely. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: myFrame is a Deedle data frame http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/csharpframe.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to build a Time Series with the Values as double, so:

```
var myTimeSeriesColumn = myFrame.GetColumn<double>("Column Title"); // Returns <series>
```

Then a new Frame can be created and later just add the columns:

```
myNewDoubleValuesFrame.AddColumn("my Column Title", myTimeSeriesColumn );
```